# Can't login to MacBook Pro because keystrokes are repeated!

Tags: macos, keyboard, login, login-screen

Every key I type in the login screen is repeated, so I can't type my correct password! (unfortunately my password is not comprised of pairs of characters)

I recently tried to speed up my key repeat rate via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490124/432311) but after reverting that change the problem is still happening. It only happens on the main login screen after boot; if I go to switch users the keyboard works normally. Fortunately I've found a workaround through the guest account, but I would really like to know how to get my main login keyboard back to normal!

Any ideas?

Comment: I've never seen this before, but something in this article might help: http://www.macissues.com/2015/04/16/fix-an-incorrect-default-keyboard-layout-at-the-os-x-login-prompt/ as with anything, make sure important data is backed-up before trying anything.

Comment: Thanks for the link @jcm. Unfortunately the first tip didn't work. (Doesn't seem like the rest is related but I may try it later anyway.)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm suffering from the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately no @Alex. But I've been working around it by enabling automatic login on boot, and the keyboard works properly on screen lock. Pretty strange bug! If you ever find a real solution please post an answer.

Comment: @Alex the answer below worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the `InitialKeyRepeat` default for the `sudo` account. I had the same problem, and noticed this that for my user account `defaults read -g InitialKeyRepeat` returned a value of 25. But `sudo defaults read -g InitialKeyRepeat` returned a value of 5, which is much faster. I changed the value for sudo using this command:

```
sudo defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 25
```

and I no longer have a problem typing my password at the logon screen. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/363252/how-to-enable-keyboard-repeat-on-a-mac) page is helpful for more details.

Comment: THANK YOU. My sudo value was at 0 somehow! I've waited 16 months for this solution :)

Comment: You're welcome! It was nearly the same amount of time for me, so I was very happy to stumble upon this.